# Is there a way to "fake-install" Ubuntu filesystem into a directory or a tar from an old .img installation medium?

Tags: system-installation, filesystem, disk-image, cd-image

Long story short, I'm trying to create an ARM architecture docker image of Ubuntu 10.04 (don't ask me why) because Docker Hub only contains the amd64 version.

The furthest I got is finding that the .img of an arm ubuntu 10.04 installation media is still available in [this archive](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ports/releases/lucid/). Sadly, I don't have an ARM machine I could actually install it onto and I've had no luck in getting it working with an emulated machine (UMT cause my machine is an M1 Mac).

I can mount the .img on my machine just fine but I just don't know how to move from various `Packages.gz` and `.deb` files scattered around a number of directories to a filesystem I'd expect post-installation.

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. It's exactly the installer that does this task ("moving various packages" etc.). If you would want to do this without running the installer, you'd basically have to replicate the installer's functionality, ie. write your own installer.

I guess that you have better chance of creating a Docker image if you can find an **already installed** ARM system and make a disk image out of it.